# New Activity bar in search page stopped appearing on all community sites

Tags: bug, search, live-refresh, web-sockets

The bar of new activities in search page such as `1 question with new activity` is no longer appearing to click.

---

## Tested browsers and OS

***Windows 11 Pro Version 21H2***

1. Google Chrome 103.0.5060.66 64bits
2. Mozilla Firefox 102.0 (64-bits)
3. Brave 1.40.109 Chromium: 103.0.5060.66 (Official Version) 64 bits

***Android 8.0.0; SM-G935F Build/R16W***

1. Chrome 103.0.5060.53
2. Brave 1.40.106, Chromium 103.0.5060.53

---

I initially asked on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418982/11462274), but I realized that the problem is happening on all sites, not just a single community.

---

## Tests already done on request via comments and surveys:

1. I've already done a complete cleaning of the saved data of the site
   in my browser and it didn't solve.
2. I have already restarted the page and the browser.
3. I've tested it in other browsers.
4. I've tested using [Websocket Indicator by CertainPerformance](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Websocket-Indicator) (WebSocket was installed after I noticed the problem → installed to test on request in a comment), so it is not the culprit of the problem), with the
   green bars but the new activities still don't appear:
   [image]
5. I've been to `DevTools → Application → Storage → Clear Site Data`.
6. Test in [Real-Time Web Test](https://websocketstest.com/):

[image]

## Current result:

[image]

## Expected Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who experience this problem in the future and none of the steps in the question work:

Contact your internet provider and provide all information regarding the StackOverflow website.

After I got in touch, a few hours later they called me saying that they had done an internal procedure related to the site, after that everything went back to normal:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, if you can get them to explain what was wrong, maybe worth adding this as well, so others in the future can tell it to their ISP and save time.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar They said they were going to send me a complete protocol of the case and what was done, they asked me for 7 days to deliver the document (I confess to you that I very much doubt they will send it, but I'll annoy them to receive it).